# Passing data from one collectionView to other collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In a `UICollectionView`, I am displaying images and on clicking the image it opens up in a ViewController. Works fine.

However, I want to swipe the images to right/left when the image opens in the new viewController.

To swipe the images, I tried adding a `CollectionView` in the `DetailViewController` and added `UIImageView` inside the cell.

```
//on clicking the image from main view controller

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
        vc?.name = imgArr[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```

The error is:

> "Illegal Configuration: The img outlet from the DetailViewController
>   to the UIImageView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to
>   repeating content."

Comment: you can you use `pageController` to achieve what you want instead of creating a new `collectionView`

Comment: You have connected IBOutlet of collection view cell in view controller class, Your cell imageview outlet should be in cell subclass that's what error says

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way for you will be to pass the whole `imgArr` as a data source for the collectionView in the `DetailViewController`. Then define a `selectedName` property in the `DetailViewController` and scroll to the selected name before `DetailViewController` has appeared.

**EDIT:**

```
//on clicking the image from main view controller

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.imgArr = imgArr
        vc.selectedNameIndex = imgArr[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
}
```